# How to create VeChain X Node? (VEN/VET)

Tags: altcoin, altcoin-trade

Let's say I have a required amount of VET to make an X Node. How do I create it?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on their [medium announcement page](https://medium.com/@vechainofficial/vechain-x-series-6b77b746b4b2):

[image]